# Conditionally autoexpand a NSOutlineView row

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

How can I expand an NSOutlineView row with some of its child rows already expanded, depending on a condition on its data?

Thanks

Comment: Implement `outlineView:isItemExpandable:`

Comment: I don't want to allow or not a item to expand. I want it to be displayed already expanded.

Comment: You have to code this yourself with `outlineViewItemDidExpand:` (or maybe `outlineViewItemWillExpand:`) and `expandItem:`.